# How to save an image to a .war file?

Tags: image, servlets, save, war, executable-jar

I have a Java project meant to let users log in and upload images to the server; a Flickr mock-up. I could save the photos a user upload inside the JBoss default server directory, but is there any way to save them in the .war file? I realize I can't save an image to the ./data folder within a war/jar file while it's in use, but how do I save them *in* the jar anyway? Is there some library I need to download?

Comment: I don't get it. The war is just your full webapp packed in one file. If you let your users upload images or whatever, that should be stored in some external directory, never "inside" your webapp.

Comment: You should also keep in mind that all uploaded images will be gone after you redeploy the whole WAR (and/or delete it).